# Pass character string of column names (e.g. "c(speed, dist") to `across` function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following toy problem.
I would like to round `drat` and `wt`.
Here is the normal way to do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars[1 ,5:7] %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(drat, wt), .fns = round))
#>           drat wt  qsec
#> Mazda RX4    4  3 16.46
```

But what I want to do is select `drat` and `wt` from the data.
Like below (doesn’t run).
How might I do this?

```r
mtcars_2 <- 
  mtcars[1 ,5:7] %>%
  bind_cols(data.frame(cols_to_modify = "c(drat, wt)"))

## view data
mtcars_2
#>           drat   wt  qsec cols_to_modify
#> Mazda RX4  3.9 2.62 16.46    c(drat, wt)

## my failed attempt
mtcars_2 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = eval(substitute(.$cols)),.fns = round))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> ℹ `..1 = across(.cols = eval(substitute(.$cols)), .fns = round)`.
#> x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `c(drat, wt)` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `substitute()` or `eval()` on character vectors. You need to parse those character vectors into language objects. Otherwise when you eval a string, you just get that string back. It's not like `eval` in other languages. One way to do the parsing is `str2lang`. Then you can inject that expression into the `across` using tidy evaulation's `!!`. For example

```
mtcars_2 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = !!str2lang(.$cols_to_modify),.fns = round))
```

Comment: Splendid! Thank you very much! Btw what do you recommend I read to finally properly understand `eval`, `str2lang`, `str2expression` and other similar functions?

Comment: You could go though the [Advanced R book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/). But really the problem here seems more to do with trying to store code as text in a column of a data.frame. It would be better not to do that in the first place. Maybe just use a list column to hold vectors of names rather than requiring a parsing step. Had to say without knowing exactly why you are trying to do this.